# How can I use the keyword $(this) in place of class selector - jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code in jQuery -

```
$(".new_makes_button").click(function(){
    if($(".new_makes_button:checked").length == 0) {
```

So how can I replace class selector ".new_makes_button" in second line of above code with $(this)? I am just in search of correct syntax. Here I have several checkboxes with class "new_makes_button" and clicking on any of it, I am checking when all the checkboxes will be unchecked then run the following code.

Comment: Do you mean `if($(this).not(":checked"))`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will check if the current item, is checked. The current item is the Event source element. `$(this)` inside the callback is a reference to a single element.

```
if(this.checked === false) {

}
```

But, if you want to find out if none of the elements with `.new_makes_button` are checked then you can use jQuery.

```
$(".new_makes_button").click(function() {
   // $(this) at this point is a reference to a 
   // single element. To get Them all you may do this:
   var total = 0;
   $(".new_makes_button").each(function(index, element) {
     if(this.checked === true) {
       total++;
     }
   });
   alert("Total checked item" + (total).toString());
});
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/LBFV4/10/)

> how can I replace class selector ".new_makes_button" in second line of
>   above code with $(this)?

If you really want to use `this` object, then you can, however, it isn't not correct syntax to not use `$(this)`.

To use `this` inside that method and have it reference an array of `.new_makes_button` elements, you can change it's value using `bind`. Here in this example, `this` will reference a jQuery object.

```
$(".new_makes_button").click(function(e) {
  // here `this` is a jquery object!
  // no need to call the `$`
  console.log(this.length);
}.bind($(".new_makes_button")));
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/GQQhj/19/)

**Shortest possible solution**

```
$(".new_makes_button").click(function(e) {
  if(this.filter(':checked').length == 0) {
     // handle condition        
   }
}.bind($(".new_makes_button")));
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
if (!$(this).is(":checked")) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just look at the checked property directly on the clicked on item like this:

```
if (!$(this).prop("checked")) {
    // code here for when the item is not checked
}
```

Once you have the DOM element (which you have in `this`), there is no need to use further selectors as you can just examine the properties of that item directly.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery, the element being acted upon is often passed to the function parameter of a jQuery function as this. It can be made into a jQuery element object by using$(this) in the function parameter, 
ex:

$('.new_makes_button').click(function(){

$(this).animate({paddingLeft: $(this).width()}, 200);

});

Comment: Ok I understand but how will you convert this code  $(".new_makes_button").click(function(){
     if($(".new_makes_button:checked").length == 0) { into one which uses 'this' rather than class selector in if condition?